# Run TypeScript compiler from Java

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

I am trying to run the TypeScript compiler from my Java application. To start, I am trying to figure out, whether I can run the compiler from command-line without Node.js:

```
$ jsc tsc.js
```

But this way I don't get any errors, nor help.

```
$ jsc tsc.js myscript.ts
```

Will get me nowhere.

It is easy to run js code directly from java (and I am hoping to run the compiler in this way), but is it possible to run TypeScript compiler without node.js?

EDIT:

I confirm the same behaviour with rhino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the [tsc](https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6dcef41a74f8#bin%2ftsc) command invokes a JS script [tsc.js](https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6dcef41a74f8#bin%2ftsc.js), which has 2 backends: Node.js and Windows Scripting Host. If any other JavaScript server supports reading and writing to a file system (like Rhino with RingoJS), it should be able to run the TypeScript compiler *tsc.js*.

Moreover, there is a fork of TypeScript compiler which claims to directly [run on Rhino](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/nobuoka/TypeScript/BrowseLatest?branch=tmp%2frun_on_rhino). So you could invoke Rhino directly from Java, without installing node.js.

Comment: Let's say I have Rhino installed, how do I install the Typescript module? Do I need to have `npm` installed as if I was using Node.js?

Answer (score 5):

I have a project, [Typescript4j](https://github.com/martypitt/typescript4j) that does precisely this.

It runs the Typescript compiler wrapped within Rhino.

I'm using it successfully within [Bakehouse](https://github.com/TheMangoFactory/bakehouse), and a non-trivial Typescript application.

Comment: No activity in the las two years, seems to be unmaintained :-(

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is `jsc node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js file1.ts`, but unfortunately that won't work with engines different than node.js.

What will work (or at least works in the browser), is using TypeScript Compiler API, instead of trying to use the CLI (you will have to program). In the browser, you do this by loading the file `node_modules/typescript/typescript.js` and then you have access to the compiler API (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) via the global `ts`. Here you have an example of how to transpile a ts string to js using the compiler API: https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me/#example=Transpiling-a-single-file

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

The TypeScript compiler is implemented in TypeScript, and can be used in any JavaScript host.

You may need to specify the full path to tsc.js

Comment: Their I/O code is only implemented for Node.js and Windows Scripting Host actually. Potentially it may run on various engines, but not without a bit of tinkering I suppose.

Comment: You may need to tweak it, but only if the I/O implementation was different - but that isn't equivalent to "it wouldn't run on another host" - you would pick one and see what needed to change.